# Splitting a light circuit into two

Tags: electrical, electrical-distribution

I currently have a simple circuit.  Three ceiling lights, and one switch.  I would like to break it into two lights on that switch and the other light on another switch.  Will I have to run all the way back to the fuse box, or how can just run the switch to the light?  Diagram please.

THANKS!

Comment: Chris first where in the world are you that may help with the answer (wire colors).
2nd are you planning on putting in a double gang box for the 2 switches(possibly least ammount of work here) or is the new switch in a different location (possibly back to the fuse box).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. USA-Iowa
Two switches will be apart from each other.

Comment: ok do you have attic access so you can get to the lights?

Comment: All in the basement, but yes, access is easy to all parts.

Comment: Is the power feed at one of the fixtures, or at the switch?

Comment: I believe it comes to the fixture that I want to separate off then to the other two fixtures, and finally to the switch.  I did see that the light closest to the last fixture (next to the switch) has a hot outlet off of it.

Answer (score 1):

ThreePhaseEel's comment is key. Most light switches I've seen are set up the same as in this [instructional PDF](http://heightslibrary.org/materials/hrrc/15-Electrical_Repairs/WIRING/CHANGING_A_PULLCHAIN_TO_WALL_SWITCH.pdf). The relevant portion from that PDF is in this illustration:
[image: wall switch illustration]

Likely, this is exactly how the switch with one light is wired. The switch with two lights starts like this and then has another run to the 2nd light box. The first light in the circuit will have 3 conductors in the wire nuts of that lamp. If you can make a run of romex NM from the single light circuit to one of the lamps of the 2 light circuit, you'll be ok.

Disconnect and cap off the feed to that other circuit as well as the wires to the unused switch. Then you can add the light to the desired circuit.

I started an illustration but that'll take longer to draw than to do the connections.